# Selecting multiple items with jQuery Sortable()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to drag multiple items simultaneously within a jquery sortable container. In this case, it's a series of nested divs within a parent div which has the sortable() behavior applied. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if you can select multiple items (say 1, 3, and 7 in one instance, and 3,4, and 8 in another), I do not believe jquery has a way to do this currently, since the event is tagged to onclick.

On the other hand, if you want to keep certain items grouped (1 and 2 are always together), just put them together in the div.